# Keep aware of transform and transform-origin anchor point on rotated container

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to rotate a container with javascript and css property transform and transform-origin, the idea is to rotate it around certain coordinates (For example a pinch gesture center between the two fingers), I'm using this simple code (snippet attached) right now to rotate the container and using the onclick event to capture the anchor point. It is working properly as long as you keep clicking without moving the cursor to a different position on the container. There's an issue when you change the click position once the container has been rotated, the expected behavior is to keep track of the transformation and start rotating for that new point, however right now the container is doing an odd jump. I think that some x,y translation need to be added to the container, but i can figure out what's the correct factor to add to the container.

I'm not sure if I've illustrated well the expected behavior, to make sure here's and example: Imagine you pin a note to a surface at certain position, then, you start rotating the note, having the pin as anchor point. Now, after rotating the note a little, you put out the pin (Keeping the note at the same place), then you place the pin on a different position on the note and rotate again with that new anchor point. That's the expected behavior, hope i have explained myself well.

Here's a snippet to show it better, also available on codepen, cheers.

http://codepen.io/vasilycrespo/pen/GZeYpB

```js
var angle = 15,
    scale = 1,
    origin = { x: 0, y: 0};
    
var transform = function (e) {
  var map = document.getElementById("map");
  angle += 15;
  map.style.transformOrigin = e.pageX + "px " + e.pageY + "px";
  map.style.transform = "rotate("+angle+"deg) scale("+ scale +")";
};
```

```css
.content{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  margin-top:0;
  margin-left:0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.square{
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-image: url(http://www.pnas.org/site/misc/images/15-02545.500.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="content" onclick="transform(event)">
  <div class="square" id="map"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: the thing is that the transform-origin points is set from the original position in the flux of your tag, not from where it is redrawn at screen :(

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that every time you click, the div changes position based on where you click. After the first click, you should save `e.pageX` and `e.pageY`, and in the next clicks you should use the saved values. You can change your `transform` function to this:

```
var transform = (function () {
  var pageX, pageY;
  return function(e) {
    if (typeof pageX === "undefined") {
      pageX = e.pageX
      pageY = e.pageY
    }
    var map = document.getElementById("map"), xr;
    angle += 15;
    map.style.transformOrigin = pageX + "px " + pageY + "px";
    map.style.transform = "rotate("+angle+"deg) scale("+ scale +")";
  }
}())
```

See [updated Code Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZWZyPR).

Comment: Thank you, but this is not the expected behavior, i mean, once you change the anchor point, the rotation should keep from that new point like on the "pin a note example", your approach is different, you keeping the original click point despite of the cursor position change, maybe i explained myself the wrong way hehe, kind of tricky to express the expected behavior.

Comment: No, almost, but is doing some kind off odd jump to the new anchor point, for example, on my implementation, click two times on the eye of the 
elephant without moving the cursor away to rotate the container a bit... then change your cursor to somewhere else, lets say the
elephant trunk tip, the idea is to keep the trunk tip as center point and keep the rotation  on. The position of the trunk tip is lost with the jump. Right now I'm trying to add some left & top based on the offset top and left of the rotated image to fix the center point, but no success yet hehe.